# Migration to Spring Boot 3 - how can I handle "keepalive@openssh.com" requests from the server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp, spring-boot-3

Our team has an application where a file is fetched and handled once per day from a remote server using Spring Integration SFTP. Right now, I am migrating from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.

After migrating to Spring Boot 3, I have noticed that the following is logged (on WARN level) every minute:

```
2023-08-15T15:00:48.427+02:00  WARN 21256 --- []-nio2-thread-3] i.DefaultSftpClient$SftpChannelSubsystem : handleUnknownChannelRequest(SftpChannelSubsystem[id=0, recipient=0]-ClientSessionImpl[<username>@<host>/<ip>:<port>][sftp]) Unknown channel request: keepalive@openssh.com[want-reply=true]
2023-08-15T15:01:48.430+02:00  WARN 21256 --- [-nio2-thread-13] i.DefaultSftpClient$SftpChannelSubsystem : handleUnknownChannelRequest(SftpChannelSubsystem[id=0, recipient=0]-ClientSessionImpl[<username>@<host>/<ip>:<port>][sftp]) Unknown channel request: keepalive@openssh.com[want-reply=true]
```

I assume that this is the Keepalive request sent from the server to the client. Why can't our application handle that request? The warning message was not shown before migrating to Spring Boot 3.

Even though the client can't handle the keepalive requests from the server, it still fetches files as it should. The problem is that the log file will be full of all these unnecessary warning messages, and we will not be able to see other important logs.

This is our Spring Bean for the SessionFactory

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpHost);
    factory.setPort(sftpPort);
    factory.setUser(sftpUser);

    if (sftpPrivateKey != null) {
        factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
    } else {
        factory.setPassword(sftpPassword);
    }

    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);

    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are facing exactly this situation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-1237.

According to their recommendation it is possible to inject an externally configured `SshClient`:

```
SshClient client = SshClient.setupDefaultClient();
List<RequestHandler<ConnectionService>> oldHandlers = client.getGlobalRequestHandlers();
List<RequestHandler<ConnectionService>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
if (GenericUtils.isNotEmpty(oldHandlers)) {
   handlers.add(oldHandlers);
}
handlers.add(KeepAliveHandler.INSTANCE);
client.setGlobalRequestHandlers(handlers);
```

and then use this ctor:

```
/**
 * Instantiate based on the provided {@link SshClient}, e.g. some extension for HTTP/SOCKS.
 * @param sshClient the {@link SshClient} instance.
 * @param isSharedSession true if the session is to be shared.
 */
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory(SshClient sshClient, boolean isSharedSession) {
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have tried the suggestion, but it only works for global requests. The keepalive requests that is sent to my application are channel requests. I have tried to find a setter method on SshClient for setting channel requests handlers, similar to setGlobalRequestHandlers, but haven't found any. Do you know if there exists such a method or if it's possible to add the KeepAliveHandler for channel requests in any other way?

Comment: Looks like a `DefaultSftpClient` has this method `protected ChannelSubsystem createSftpChannelSubsystem(ClientSession clientSession) {` you can override and add it using that `ChannelSubsystem.addRequestHandler()`.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to do it, but I don't know how. I know that I can create a custom class that extends `DefaultSftpClient` and override `createSftpChannelSubsystem()`, but I don't understand how I can make `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` use my custom class instead of the instance created at [Github - DefaultSftpSessionFactory Line 283](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-sftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/session/DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java#L283). 

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I see what you mean. Please, raise a GH issue and we will think how to expose that option on a SessionFactory. I think something like protected method as a factory for the client to override should be enough.

Comment: Thanks Artem! I have now created a [GH issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8713)

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into this same issue, and solved it by creating a custom SFTP Session Factory that ignored the Keep Alive requests (inspired by Artem Bilan's answer pointing to the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` class).

The warning logs are produced by the `AbstractConnectionService.handleUnknownRequest()` (see [Github code](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/2c62c7251934fc700c810c4a4249044f3c27d7e9/sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/common/session/helpers/AbstractConnectionService.java#L891)), because the `AbstractConnectionService.globalRequest()` was not able to find a `RequestHandler` that could handle the `keepalive@openssh.com` request (see [Github code](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/2c62c7251934fc700c810c4a4249044f3c27d7e9/sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/common/session/helpers/AbstractConnectionService.java#L865-L883)).

You can read more about Global Requests in [Apache's Mine-sshd documentation](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/docs/technical/global_requests.md).

So the trick to make the warnings go away is to provide a Global Request Handler that reacts to the `keepalive@openssh.com` request. Unfortunately, the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` doesn't allow you to append an extra Handler, so you'll need more or less to create your own Session, and your own Session Factory.

Here is a sample of the custom SFTP Session Factory:

```
import org.apache.sshd.client.ClientBuilder;
import org.apache.sshd.client.SshClient;
import org.apache.sshd.client.auth.keyboard.UserInteraction;
import org.apache.sshd.client.auth.password.PasswordIdentityProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.client.global.OpenSshHostKeysHandler;
import org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier;
import org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.RejectAllServerKeyVerifier;
import org.apache.sshd.client.keyverifier.ServerKeyVerifier;
import org.apache.sshd.common.channel.RequestHandler;
import org.apache.sshd.common.session.ConnectionService;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.ResourceKnownHostsServerKeyVerifier;

import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class CustomSftpSessionFactory extends DefaultSftpSessionFactory {
    private static final List<RequestHandler<ConnectionService>> GLOBAL_REQUEST_HANDLERS = asList(
        OpenSshHostKeysHandler.INSTANCE,
        CustomOpenSshKeepAliveHandler.INSTANCE
    );

    public CustomSftpSessionFactory(String password) {
        super(setUpDefaultClient(password), false);
    }

    private static SshClient setUpDefaultClient(String password) {
        // Taken from the SshClient.setUpDefaultClient()
        final ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.builder();
        clientBuilder.globalRequestHandlers(GLOBAL_REQUEST_HANDLERS);

        // Taken from DefaultSftpSessionFactory.doInitInnerClient()
        // It would be analogous to the factory.setAllowUnknownKeys()
        clientBuilder.serverKeyVerifier(AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier.INSTANCE);

        final SshClient sshClient = clientBuilder.build();

        // This is analogous to the factory.setPassword()
        sshClient.setPasswordIdentityProvider(PasswordIdentityProvider.wrapPasswords(password));

        sshClient.setUserInteraction(UserInteraction.NONE);

        // You may configure other SSH Client properties, like Private Keys.

        return sshClient;
    }
}
```

Notice that the `GLOBAL_REQUEST_HANDLERS` contains 2 handlers:

- First the default `OpenSshHostKeysHandler` that is normally provided when using the `SshClient.setUpDefaultClient()` (see the `DEFAULT_GLOBAL_REQUEST_HANDLERS` in `org.apache.sshd.client.ClientBuilder`).
- And then a second one, which is the custom one that allows us to handle (and ignore) those keep alive requests.

The implementation of the second one would be something like this:

```
import org.apache.sshd.common.channel.RequestHandler;
import org.apache.sshd.common.global.AbstractOpenSshHostKeysHandler;
import org.apache.sshd.common.session.Session;
import org.apache.sshd.common.util.buffer.Buffer;
import org.apache.sshd.common.util.buffer.keys.BufferPublicKeyParser;

import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomOpenSshKeepAliveHandler extends AbstractOpenSshHostKeysHandler {
    public static final CustomOpenSshKeepAliveHandler INSTANCE = new CustomOpenSshKeepAliveHandler();

    private static final String REQUEST = "keepalive@openssh.com";

    public CustomOpenSshKeepAliveHandler() {
        super(REQUEST);
    }

    public CustomOpenSshKeepAliveHandler(BufferPublicKeyParser<? extends PublicKey> parser) {
        super(REQUEST, parser);
    }

    protected RequestHandler.Result handleHostKeys(Session session, Collection<? extends PublicKey> keys, boolean wantReply, Buffer buffer) {
        // KeepAlive request is ignored, by lying that there was an actual reply.
        return Result.Replied;
    }
}
```

And finally, all that would be left to do is to use it. Like this, for example:

```
final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new CustomSftpSessionFactory(password);
factory.setHost(host);
factory.setPort(port);
factory.setUser(username);
```

**BEWARE:** I'm not 100% sure about the implications of ignoring the KeepAlive requests, so please consider implementing an actual reply instead of just copy pasting the Custom Handler code above.