Migrated from Spring Integration 5.5 to 6.2.3 and cannot configure Keep Alive for sftp
After upgrade to Spring Integration 6.2.3 from 5.5 the DefaultSftpSessionFactory seems to lose keep alive config methods:
defaultSftpSessionFactory.setServerAliveInterval(keepAliveInterval);
defaultSftpSessionFactory.setServerAliveCountMax(keepAliveCountMax);

With the new version there's a change from using com.jcraft.jsch to org.apache.sshd.sftp which is responsible for SftpClient configuration
But I struggle to find proper methods to set the properties
What else the new upgrade brought is a warning message about keep alive that I found some suggestions in another SO topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76907200/1873995 however they don't work. It relates to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-1237 but the code was merged to master with no release yet
Warning message:
2024-05-14T10:09:46.686+02:00  WARN 29596 --- [-nio2-thread-12] i.DefaultSftpClient$SftpChannelSubsystem : handleUnknownChannelRequest(SftpChannelSubsystem[id=0, recipient=0]-ClientSessionImpl[my-ftp@ftp-server.com/123.123.123.22:22][sftp]) Unknown channel request: keepalive@proftpd.org[want-reply=true]
I have no clue from where the message is being started and why there's this address specified: keepalive@proftpd.org as I don't have it hardcoded anywhere
The suggested code to create custom SshClient and also a suggestion to use a custom DefaultSftpSessionFactory with a handler that's gonna handled Unknown channel requests but the following code also fails to reach that goal
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        SshClient client = customSshClient();

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new CustomSftpSessionFactory(client, reuseSession);
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(username);
//        if (keepAliveInterval > 0) { // TODO
//            factory.setServerAliveInterval(keepAliveInterval);
//            factory.setServerAliveCountMax(keepAliveCountMax); 
//        }
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }

    private SshClient customSshClient() {
        final SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
        List<RequestHandler<ConnectionService>> oldHandlers = client.getGlobalRequestHandlers();
        List<RequestHandler<ConnectionService>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
        if (GenericUtils.isNotEmpty(oldHandlers)) {
            handlers.addAll(oldHandlers);
        }
        handlers.add(KeepAliveHandler.INSTANCE);
        client.setGlobalRequestHandlers(handlers);
        client.addPasswordIdentity(password);
        client.setServerKeyVerifier(AcceptAllServerKeyVerifier.INSTANCE);
        return client;
    }

public class CustomSftpSessionFactory extends DefaultSftpSessionFactory {

    public CustomSftpSessionFactory(final SshClient sshClient, final boolean isSharedSession) {
        super(sshClient, isSharedSession);
    }

    @Override
    protected SftpClient createSftpClient(ClientSession clientSession, SftpVersionSelector initialVersionSelector, SftpErrorDataHandler errorDataHandler) throws IOException {
        SftpClient client = super.createSftpClient(clientSession, initialVersionSelector, errorDataHandler);
        client.getSession().setUnknownChannelReferenceHandler(new CustomUnknownChannelReferenceHandler());
//        client.getClientSession().setUnknownChannelReferenceHandler(new CustomUnknownChannelReferenceHandler());

        return client;
    }

    protected class CustomUnknownChannelReferenceHandler implements UnknownChannelReferenceHandler {

        @Override
        public Channel handleUnknownChannelCommand(ConnectionService service, byte cmd, long channelId, Buffer buffer) throws IOException {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

PS. I tried to also set logging level to ERROR to hide the messages but no luck there as well
org.apache.sshd.common.channel: ERROR
The question is: how to get rid of the warning message and how to setup the keep alive settings?
